# How to pick files/folders to archive in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have a direcory structure like below:

```
-src/
   --common/
      test.py
   --dev/
      config.json
   --prd/
      config.json
```

I want to create an archive that zips the common folder and environment specific folder contents:

```
test.zip
--test.py
--config.json
```

Terraform [archive_file](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/archive/latest/docs/data-sources/archive_file) allows for zipping the whole directory using `source_dir` or single files using `source` or `source_file` but it doesn't allow to mix them something like:

```
data "archive_file" "archive" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "./src/common/test.py
  source_dir  = "./src/${var.env}/"
  output_path = "./src/${var.env}/test.zip"
}
```

Is there any other way to do this in terraform?

Comment: I've used only `source` attribute from `archive_file` resource along with `template_file` to be able to pick files from different directories. Not very elegant solution but works for now.

Answer (score 0):

The other way would be to use [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) with custom zipping functionality. Alternatively, you could create a [custom data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) which would not only perform custom zip operation, but also could return a custom data to your TF for further use.